# How to filter a set of value from matrix with criteria in a vector without a loop?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix source (A), with first column is key, and the second is value for each key.

```
__0_1                    22034
__1000000000000_1        34310
__1000000000000_2        38608
__1000000000_1           18829
__1000_1                 38674
__11_november_1          21566
__11_plus_1              35908
__12_1                   25784
__14_july_1              28671
__15_may_organization_1  36358
```

And vector B is the subset of key to need assign value base on matrix A.
B:

```
__14_july_1
__1000000000_1
_15_may_organization_1
```

Here is my code to find value for B from matrix A:

```
for (i in 1:length(B)){
 rlst<-A[A[,1]==B[i],2];
}
```

It work good with A & B small. But my real data is very big, and for loop make me lost a lot of time.
I tried some command like %in%,subset. But it not working for my problem. 
Please help me solve this problem without `for`.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the 3rd entry for `B` - should it be `__15_may_organization_1`? Also are you sure you want to use a `matrix` for `A` when you have both character and numeric data? I assume a `data.frame` might be better.

Comment: What about: `rlst<-A[A[,1] %in% B,2]`? Is it faster? Is it working at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you only expect exactly one match for each value of B. Here are your sample data sets

```
A<-data.frame(
    V1 = c("__0_1", "__1000000000000_1", "__1000000000000_2", 
    "__1000000000_1", "__1000_1", "__11_november_1", "__11_plus_1", 
    "__12_1", "__14_july_1", "__15_may_organization_1"), 
    V2 = c(22034L, 
    34310L, 38608L, 18829L, 38674L, 21566L, 35908L, 25784L, 28671L, 
    36358L)
)
B<-c("__14_july_1", "__15_may_organization_1", "__1000000000_1")
```

(notice I actually switched the position of two values in `B`.)

Two ways you can extract the data you want are

```
A[A[,1] %in% B, ]
#                         V1    V2
# 4           __1000000000_1 18829
# 9              __14_july_1 28671
# 10 __15_may_organization_1 36358
```

and

```
A[match(B,A[,1]),]
#                         V1    V2
# 9              __14_july_1 28671
# 10 __15_may_organization_1 36358
# 4           __1000000000_1 18829
```

Note that first way preserves the order of the rows in `A`, while the second method returns the rows in order of `B` which seems to be closest to what your loop would have done.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data.table` package:

```
require(data.table)
A<-data.frame(
     V1 = c("__0_1", "__1000000000000_1", "__1000000000000_2", 
            "__1000000000_1", "__1000_1", "__11_november_1", "__11_plus_1", 
            "__12_1", "__14_july_1", "__15_may_organization_1"), 
     V2 = c(22034L, 
            34310L, 38608L, 18829L, 38674L, 21566L, 35908L, 25784L, 28671L, 
            36358L)
 )
B<-c("__14_july_1", "__15_may_organization_1", "__1000000000_1")
A <- data.table(A)
setkey(A,V1)
A[B]
                        V1    V2
1:             __14_july_1 28671
2: __15_may_organization_1 36358
3:          __1000000000_1 18829
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(data.frame(V1=B), A)
#Joining by: "V1"
#                    V1    V2
#1             __14_july_1 28671
#2 __15_may_organization_1 36358
#3          __1000000000_1 18829
```